# Javascript try catch error - function expected

Tags: javascript, exception, try-catch, content-length

I am developing windows app in windows phone Silverlight 8.1 solution.

when i am using the try catch i get error saying funtion expected.

Here is my piece of code:

```
try
{
    alert("blogCategoryId is : " + blogCategoryId.length());
}
catch (err) {
    alert("Error is :" + err.message);
}
```

And is there alternative of .length() funtion.

Comment: `length` is a property, not a function. (assuming that `blogCategoryId` is an `Array`)

Comment: error itself suggests that you are invoking a function for a variable which is not. what is the ouput of `typeof length`?

Comment: I want to get the length of blogCategoryId. what should i do.?

Comment: `blogCategoryId.length` should do. But it depends on how blogCategoryId is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to get the each element of blogCategoryId if the elements are more than 1, and i got it with the following code:

```
if (blogCategoryId.length>1)
{
    var digits = ("" + blogCategoryId).split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        alert("The length is greater :"+digits[i]);
    }
}
```